# JS: Drag and drop image in a search engine interface

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, lemur

I'm building a search engine interface. I've got some webpages raw content (including images) in Lemur indexes. I want to drag and drop images and implement image searching later. I know how to make an image draggable in HTML by setting draggable="True". But it's not a good choice for me to change raw contents in Lemur indexes. Is there any way that I can implement image drag and drop in my main.js?

BTW, I current implement text drag and drop by:
var selection=document.getElementById('lemurbox').contentWindow.getSelection();

But this seem can only get text since the selection will be NULL after dragging a image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at jQuery UI? They have these functionalities built into their scripts. You can test all of them out at http://jqueryui.com/